# How can I make label and caption as in the snapshot using package "caption"?

Tags: captions, labels

I'm trying to make a figure caption and label as highlighted in the snapshot for a paper (I have many figures). I wondering if anyone could help me to make it using the "caption" package.

Thank you for your help in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=FIGURE,labelfont={blue}}
```

This will change the Figure labels to something very similar to what you showed.   In order to also make the caption font smaller and in bold you can add:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=FIGURE,labelfont={blue, bf, footnotesize}}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but how can I make "FIGURE" with bold font and also make the caption and label smaller font than the text. If you look at the picture, it has a smaller font than the text of the paper.

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer with the details of how to do that ("bold font and also make the caption and label smaller font than the text").

Comment: Just a small comment on your nice answer:
I added the whole caption has "Sans Serif family" font and the size of whole caption is footnotsize, so I ended up as follows: 

\captionsetup{font={sf,footnotesize},labelfont={blue,bf}}